# Rename several columns (variable number)

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a dataset where the last columns indicate the number of stops extracted from that dataset.

```
ColA  ColB  ColC  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  (...)
 a     g     c    a  q  e  r  e  r  q  g  h  q   (...)
```

What I want is to select from column `1`, until the last column, and add `Stop` before it, ending up with `Stop1`, `Stop2`, etc...
The problem is that those columns can vary. Sometimes I have 10 after `1` other times I have 6.

I've tried with dplyr and data.table but I'm not sure how to automate this.

EDIT: ColA to ColC are fixed and always the same.

Comment: Are the first columns  (`ColA`,  `ColB`,  and `ColC`) fixed ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri  Yes they are. I'll add that info on the question.

Comment: @MarcoSandri works perfectly. However, how could I select from column `1` rather from position 4? That would even be more flexible in case the first columns would vary.

Comment: @MarcoSandri Probably I didn't explain it correctly. The code you wrote, simply replaces every column's name from the 1st column. What I meant was how can I rename the columns starting from the column named `1`, being that before there might be n columns.

Comment: I posted a possibile solution for your problem. If you find it useful, please upvote my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, this is a sufficiently flexible code that should solve your problem. Start considering the following dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rpois(130, 20),ncol=13))
names(df) <- c(paste("Col",LETTERS[1:3],sep=""),as.character(1:10))
df

#######
   ColA ColB ColC  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1    17   21   20 13 13 15 29 25 16 15 12 23 17
2    25   17   11 24 23 14 22 23 25 14 18 19 15
3    25   18   22 18 19 30 16 19 23 27 18 19 11
4    21   18   24 25 23 19 19 18 27 23 18 16 18
5    13   21   16 18 21 23 22 18 22 24 22 26 15
6    22   16   17 27 17 20 24 24 14 21 19 17 15
7    23   23   18 22 16 16 20 18 21 27 17 22 14
8    22   22   17 17 26 13 19 25 24 17 15 13 20
9    18   24   21 22 28 26 15 22 23 20 19 15 27
10   26   23   19 16 18 20 17 25 16 20 19 18 19
```

Now rename columuns as required:

```
k <- which(names(df)=="1")
names(df)[k:ncol(df)] <- paste("Stop",1:(ncol(df)-k+1),sep="")
df

#############
   ColA ColB ColC Stop1 Stop2 Stop3 Stop4 Stop5 Stop6 Stop7 Stop8 Stop9 Stop10
1    17   21   20    13    13    15    29    25    16    15    12    23     17
2    25   17   11    24    23    14    22    23    25    14    18    19     15
3    25   18   22    18    19    30    16    19    23    27    18    19     11
4    21   18   24    25    23    19    19    18    27    23    18    16     18
5    13   21   16    18    21    23    22    18    22    24    22    26     15
6    22   16   17    27    17    20    24    24    14    21    19    17     15
7    23   23   18    22    16    16    20    18    21    27    17    22     14
8    22   22   17    17    26    13    19    25    24    17    15    13     20
9    18   24   21    22    28    26    15    22    23    20    19    15     27
10   26   23   19    16    18    20    17    25    16    20    19    18     19
```

I hope it can help you.